# How can I restart a docker image instead of restarting docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to automate the deployment of a docker image on shinyproxy via bash scripting.

When I make changes to the dockerfile, I rebuild the dockerfile via:
`sudo docker build -t test/app1`

I have to restart docker via `sudo service docker restart`
 to see the changes.

Is there a faster one line commaned I can use for bash scripting to update the docker image to replace `sudo service docker restart`.

Thanks.

Comment: There might be a newfangled way with docker compose, but....   
docker stop test/app1
docker rm test/app1
docker build test/app1
docker start test/app1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to (re)launch a new container with the latest image to see the changes. This can be automated in a script easily as below:

```
$ docker stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
$ docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
$ docker run [OPTIONS] NEW_IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Docker has a comparatively fast startup time so don't be scared from launching new containers whenever you create a new image.